# Custom route endpoint for WP-REST API gives "code": "rest_no_route", error

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I am following [this](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-rest-api-customizing-endpoints-adding-new-ones/) tutorial to create custom end points to WP-API .

I am always getting this error  on hitting **/wp-json/custom-plugin/v2/get-all-post-ids/** on **postman** to test :

```
{
    "code": "rest_no_route",
    "message": "No route was found matching
    the URL and request method ", 
    "data": {
        "status": 404
    }
}
```

I have created a custom-plugin.php file in /plugins/custom-plugin/ directory .

```
<?php
    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'dt_register_api_hooks' );

    function dt_register_api_hooks() {    

        register_rest_route( 'custom-plugin/v2', '/get-all-post-ids/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'dt_get_all_post_ids',
            ) 
            );
    }
    // Return all post IDs
    function dt_get_all_post_ids() {
        if ( false === ( $all_post_ids = get_transient( 'dt_all_post_ids' ) ) ) {
            $all_post_ids = get_posts( array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_type'   => 'post',
                'fields'      => 'ids',
            ) );
            // cache for 2 hours
            set_transient( 'dt_all_post_ids', $all_post_ids, 60*60*2 );
        }
        return $all_post_ids;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you ever get this? It seems that sometimes `register_rest_route` just doesn't work sometimes?

Comment: @BenRacicot yes this works always , you can check a simple implementation here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/227127/92345

Comment: If it did not work, try resaving permalinks.

Comment: I've had similar problem and was able to figure it out by tracing it down step by step. Try first request /wp-json/. Do you find your routes and endpoints in the json? If yes, try /wp-json/custom-plugin/v2. What do you use in that json?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I have the same problem here

Comment: @DiogenesOliveiraJunior try checking this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223757/how-to-use-wp-rest-api-to-login-user-and-get-user-data-for-android-app/227127#227127

Answer (score 3):

Ensure your callback to `add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'dt_register_api_hooks' );` is being run.

In my case, my callback was not being called because I was using `add_action('rest_api_init', ...)` too late; the action had already fired. As in, my call to `register_rest_route()` never even happened.

Comment: And how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

I hope my answer can be useful to some as well.

For a very similar problem, while I was designing an API in WordPress, I also got the same `"code": "rest_no_route",...` error on some websites and not on other ones. I traced it back to the fact that POST requests were transformed into GET requests so they weren't recognized by my plugin.
The conversion from POST to GET was made before WordPress even started. I was able to pinpoint the problem and solve it by adding the following header, as explained [in details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75153443/1287856):

```
headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
```