# HTTP POST request gets transformed to GET request

Tags: jquery, web-services, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

How exactly does the WireCloud proxy work? We use the following code for a request via the WireCloud proxy:

```
MashupPlatform.http.makeRequest(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        forceProxy: true,
        onSuccess: function (response) {
            success(response);
        },
        onFailure: function (response) {
            error(response);
        },
        onComplete: function () {
            complete();
        }
    });
```

The browser network analysis shows that a POST request gets send to `https://example.com/cdp/https/rest.example.com/path/to/service`. Our webservice that gets called by the url however logs, that it receives a GET request.

The access log of our rest service hosted by a tomcat shows:

```
192.168.60.221 - - [26/May/2016:10:38:31 +0200] "GET /path/to/service HTTP/1.1" 405 1013
192.168.60.221 - - [26/May/2016:10:38:42 +0200] "POST /path/to/service HTTP/1.1" 204 -
```

The first call is done with the `MashupPlatform.http.makeRequest` call listed above, the second call is done with jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: null,
        success: success
    });
```

This works perfeclty fine when we set the CORS header in our webservice.

So what may be the reason, that WireClouds proxy does not work as expected?

Comment: _Our webservice that gets called by the url however logs_  what does it log? and where?

Comment: The tomcat loggs the requested url and the request method in its access log.

Comment: @Newbird, it's better to provide a snippet with the logs (you can remove any private data previously). If you don't provide that data, we are unable to review it for detecting the problem (See the [stackoverflow guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details). Another source of info that can be useful in this case is the request info provided by the developers tools of the browser.

Comment: The logs are added to the post now. I thought they might not be that interesting since you can only read from it, if a post or a get request got received by the tomcat.
The request info from the browser was already stated in my question: 'The browser network analysis shows that a POST request gets send.' I also added the called URL with the post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of widgets and operators using the `MashupPlatform` API and the WireCloud's CORS proxy and we have never see it transforming `POST` requests into `GET` requests. Anyway, it's fine to use jQuery ;-). Moreover, you can also use it for performing requests to services not supporting the CORS headers by using the [`buildProxyURL` method](http://wirecloud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/widgetapi/widgetapi/#mashupplatformhttpbuildproxyurl-method). E.g:

```js
url = MashupPlatform.http.buildProxyURL('https://api.example.com/api/endpoing');
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: null,
    success: success
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @Alvaro's answer is the right one, mine might help other users that encountered a similar issue  WordPress: a POST request was transformed in a GET requests on some servers.
It turns out that I needed to add the following header that mimics what WordPress usually accepts as POST requests.

```
method: "POST",
headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' },
...
```

Other ways to make it work for a `XMLHTTPRequest` object named `oReq`:

```
oReq.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
```

And in PHP that helped too:

```
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"));
```

**Why**?

Debugging my requests and comparing them to the requests WordPress receives when editing regular posts indicated that my requests were automatically given the header `"content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"`, which caused trouble.