# WP_REST_Request return rest_no_route (404) for custom endpoint

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I created a custom endpoint for the WordPress API-REST. I can access it normally via browser. But when I try to access it via WP_REST_Request, I get a message of "rest_no_route (404)"

```
<?php 

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'custom_routes_rifa');

function custom_routes_rifa(){

    
    register_rest_route(
      'pluginrifa/v2', '/infos/', array(
        'methods'       => 'GET',
        'callback'      => 'api_rifa_infos',
        'show_in_index' => false
      )
    );

}
```

If I put /wp-json/pluginrifa/v2/infos/?rifa=140 in the browser everything works as it should, but the code below returns 404:

```
<?php
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp-json/pluginrifa/v2/infos' );
$request->set_query_params( [ 'rifa' => 140 ] );
$response = rest_do_request( $request );
$server = rest_get_server();
$data = $server->response_to_data( $response, false );
$json = wp_json_encode( $data );
          
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

I found this discussion [Custom route endpoint for WP-REST API gives "code": "rest_no_route", error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645019/custom-route-endpoint-for-wp-rest-api-gives-code-rest-no-route-error) but none of the proposed solutions resolved, apart from apparently be something different, as it works via HTTP, but via WP_REST_Request it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, I had to replace:

```
<?php $request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp-json/pluginrifa/v2/infos' );
```

to

```
<?php $request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET','/pluginrifa/v2/infos' );
```

/wp-json/ needs to be omitted from the request. I don't know why, but in several places on the internet, the examples for new WP_REST_Request are using wp-json in the URL. Perhaps, this has fallen on some WordPress update

Comment: Just find out that `/wp-json/` has to be included in the URL for async **js** requests on a site page, but it has to be dropped for internal **php** requests.

Answer (score 0):

**Tyler Collier** has the correct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66377175/11959252). Based on his advice that:

> **Ensure your callback to add_action( 'rest_api_init',**
> **'dt_register_api_hooks' ); is being run.**

We used PHP code that follows, in our *WordPress*, to resolve the BUG appearing in our *Android Studio*'s *Logcat*:

> **I  Webhook response: {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was**
> **found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}**

```
// Register the custom webhook route
function register_custom_webhook_route() {
    register_rest_route('my-webhooks/v1', '/webhook/text', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'handle_webhook_request',
    ));
}

// Ensure the callback to register_custom_webhook_route is being run
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_custom_webhook_route');
```

Our error was putting an `if !function_exists` check on the `'register_custom_webhook_route'` function.

The code relies on *WP Rest API* plugin and can be viewed in full at [this](https://github.com/salmanshuaib/cellnet/blob/main/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-webhooks/my-webhooks.php) **GitHub** link. The repo, **cellnet**, pulls text messages from your mobilephone and posts to your WordPress website based on authorization keywords.